# Limit a generic type argument only to be a int, double or custom class

Tags: dart

I trying make the following code but T only can be int, double or a custom class. I couldn't find how to restrict the type in **Dart** or something that work like **where** from **C#**. How can I do that in Dart?

```
class Array3dG<T> extends ListBase<T> {
  List<T> l = List<T>();
  Array3dG(List<T> list) {
    l = list;
  }
  set length(int newLength) { l.length = newLength; }
  int get length => l.length;
  T operator [](int index) => l[index];
  void operator []=(int index, T value) { l[index] = value; }
}
```

Comment: When you say "custom class" what does that imply? For me it sounds like any class so the question should more be what makes this "custom class" special?

Comment: In that case, Is another class created by my self to handle with lists too: `class Array1dG<T> extends ListBase<T> ... `. There is nothing special about that class, just another class.

Comment: If there are nothing special about the class why not allow all classes? I mean, if you have some requirement for the class you can specify that as <T extends SomeInterface>. I am just trying to understand the problem so I can give the best solution. As your have mentioned, Dart does not have "where" from C#.

Comment: In my case, my class can handle only with numbers types or some classes of a specific type that can handle numbers too. If the user put the T = String, for example, all the class will broke, because of  this I want to limit the possibles types of T. I thinking to solve this checking the type T in the constructor and throw a exception, but I don't if it is a good solution.

Comment: The problem to use <T extends SomeInterface> is I can only extends from one Interface or class, but in my case, I need to allow more than one type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to constrain the type variable at compile-time. You can only have one bound on a type variable, and the only bound satisfying both `int` and your custom class is `Object`.

As suggested by @Mattia, you can check at run-time and throw in the constructor if the type parameter is not one of the ones you supprt:

```
Array3dG(this.list) { 
  if (this is! Array3dG<int> && 
      this is! Array3dG<double> && 
      this is! Array3dG<MyClass>) {
    throw ArgumentError('Unsupported element type $T');
  }
}
```

This prevents creating an instance of something wrong, but doesn't catch it at compile-time.

Another option is to have factory methods instead of constructors:

```
class Array3dG<T> {
  List<T> list;
  Array3dG._(this.list);
  static Array3dG<int> fromInt(List<int> list) => Array3dG<int>._(list);      
  static Array3dG<int> fromDouble(List<double> list) => Array3dG<double>._(list);      
  static Array3dG<MyClass> fromMyClass(List<MyClass> list) => Array3dG<MyClass>._(list);
  ...
}
```

which you then use as `Array3dG.fromInt(listOfInt)`. It looks like a named constructor, but it is just a static factory method (so no using `new` in front).

Comment: Do you know if there is any proposal to Dart lang to support this validation at compile time?

Comment: That would be https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/83

Comment: OMG, It's open since november 2018! That will not solved soon with such low priority.

Comment: Very likely correct. It's an open feature request for the language, one among very many. No-one has yet promised to actually add it to the language, and it's not among the currently highest prioritized features being looked at. So yes, it might never happen - or it might happen quickly if the feature becomes a high priority for some reason. (That pretty much describes every language feature request that isn't currently being actively worked on).

Answer (score 1):

You can check at runtime the type with the `is` keyword:

```dart
Array3dG(List<T> list) {
   if (list is List<int>) {
        //Handle int
   }
   else if (list is List<double>) {
        //Handle double
   }
   else if (list is List<MyClass>) {
        //Handle MyClass
   }
   else {
       throw ArgumentError('Unsupported $T type');
   }
  }
```

Note that if you are handling `int` and `double` in the same way you can just check for `num`

You can check the progress of the Union types here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/4938

Comment: Thank you, I think the runtime check type is the only solution. Can you edit you answer and change the last `else if` to `else` or `else if (T is MyClass2)` ?

Comment: Oh, that was a type while copy-pasting, I've edited my answer

Comment: This code *does not work*. You are checking the type of an expression `T` which has type `Type`, not whether the type variable is a subtype of the mentioned type. (Also, never throw `Exception`, use an `Error` for programming error. This may be an `ArgumentError`).

Comment: @lrn Thanks for the help, now the code should for properly